# How can I get the text from a dialogue using selenium-python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dialog

I want to crawl the dialogue text in a **popup window**. The problem is that after I triggered the link the window appears but it seems that the selenium driver cannot handle it automatically as I learned from other questions on this site by entering `driver.window_handles`. 
The source of the trigger:

[image]

The value of `len(driver.window_handles)` is 1. I thought I can get the window element and then get the text via the `get_attributes`, fortunately I succeeded getting the element by

```
wd = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[node-type="repeat_list"]')
```

> selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="f810cbbe-db43-4e8d-b484-664559ec8efc", element="{dd00e689-7991-44e9-85d3-76c69e79218f}")

But the sad thing is I don't know how to get all the stuff out from it since I don't know their attributes.

I'm not certain if it's a dialogue, a front end engineer told me that it looks like an animation. Anyway this is the source snippet:

[image]

PS: the browser is **Firefox**.

I thought it may violate the **site's Acceptable Use Policy** to crawl then I should hide some information. Sorry.

Comment: Could you share the `HTML` you're working with?

Comment: is it a window popup or new window

Comment: @sai A window popup, methinks. However I have fetched the dialogue text from the subelement of the element `wd` aforementioned I want to know how to handle the popup dialogue window to optimize my existing solution.

Comment: Please post the HTML as text instead of a picture. Posting code as an image is strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your parent element :

```
wd = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[node-type="repeat_list"]')
```

you can continue calling methods on this object, and in this order reach the children elements, you can use find `element_by_xpath`, or `find element_by_class name`, for example:

```
wd = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[node-type="repeat_list"]')
wd.find_element_by_class_name("list_box").find_element_by_class_name("list_ul").find_elements_by_class_name("list_li S_line1 clearfix")
```

and so on until you reach the desired element down the hierarchy and extract it's content as you wish.

I hope this helps!

Comment: You're right, but I think there may be a method for the dialogue window.

Comment: There is no such method in selenium. as you mentioned above the len(driver.window.handles) is 1 therefor the dialog window is considered  to be a part of the current HTML page the driver is focused on, in selenium there are methods to handle alerts but only because an alert is a special kind of event triggered by the browser, once the dialog box is part of the HTML hierarchy you must treat it as such.